# Create Windows 10 install USB with Boot Camp Assistant

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, iso-image, osx-el-capitan

I cannot create a Windows 10 install USB from OSX. I only get Windows 7 as an option in the Bootcamp USB wizard and it fails to boot from the USB when I try it.

The ISO is downloaded from Microsoft and I've tried to re-download it. The USB flash drive worked with a Ubuntu LiveUSB created with unetbootin.

[image]

**Note:** My intent is to install this on a PC, Bootcamp Assistant just seemed to be the easiest way to create the USB key on a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're not getting an option for Windows 7. You're getting an option for **Windows 7 or Later**. Bootcamp can be used with Windows 8, 8.1, and 10.

However with that said, it is not a general utility for making a bootable Windows USB disk. It's for making installing Windows alongside OSX **on a Mac**.

Apparently, [according to this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/123876/148618) and the subsequent comments and sources, you could do this (use the USB disk on a normal PC) but only for **Windows 7 ISOs**.

**My suggestion** to you, since I can't seem to find any utilities for Mac for creating *bootable* Windows USB drives from ISOs, is to simply install Windows alongside Mac using Bootcamp, then on that install of Windows download the [media creation utility](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/media-creation-tool-install) and use it to create a proper bootable USB drive.

Comment: [In this guide there's a screenshot](http://osxdaily.com/2015/06/22/make-windows-10-install-usb-drive-from-mac-os-x/) with Windows 8 option. The ISO can easily be obtained [at Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO).

Comment: Okay, but the point remains that you can't use bootcamp to make a Windows 10 bootable USB disk for another PC. On my bootcamp it said Windows 7 or later and I successfully installed Windows 10 Pro alongside OSX on my Mac.

Comment: You're right, I didn't read the guide properly. I successfully created a installer USB by installing Win 10 on Virtualbox on my Mac, then using the Win 10 media creation tool. It didn't work with Sandisk USB keys, but another key worked fine.